# NDWI Calculation with LANDSAT7

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to claculate the NDWI values for some plots that I research in Africa using LANDSAT 7. it seems like the code work, but when I try to visualize the polygons, I get only parts of them (see image)

[image: the dark area is the RGB median image from Landsat 7, the orange part is the NDWI calcualtion]

the dark area is the RGB median image from Landsat 7, the orange part is the NDWI calcualtion for the same geometry as the geometry of the RGB polygon.

i'm worried because my end goal is to get statistics for this area for many years, but I found out  that when I try to visualize specific images from the Image Collection, some of them can't be visualized, even though they have values.

this is the code I have written:

```
var geometry=plot2;
/**
 * Function to mask clouds based on the pixel_qa band of Landsat SR data.
 * @param {ee.Image} image Input Landsat SR image
 * @return {ee.Image} Cloudmasked Landsat image
 */
var cloudMaskL457 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // If the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
  // or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel.
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
                  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
  // Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2).divide(10000)
  .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start']);
};

//Create LANDSAT7 dataset

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate('1999-01-01', '2019-07-01')
                  .select('B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','pixel_qa')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .map(cloudMaskL457);




//RGB visualization

var visParams = {
  bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1'],
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  gamma: 1.4,
};
// Map.centerObject(geometry);
// Map.addLayer(dataset.median(), visParams);

//clip the dataset according to the geometry
var clippedCol=dataset.map(function(im){ 
  return im.clip(geometry);
});

//test if clipping the image collection worked
Map.centerObject(geometry);
Map.addLayer(clippedCol.median(),visParams, 'RGB TEST');

// Get the number of images.
var count = dataset.size();
print('Count: ',count);
//print(clippedCol);
print(dataset,'dataset');

//function to calculate NDWI in LANDSAT7
var addNDWI = function(image) {
  var NDWI = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B5'])
  .rename('NDWI')
  .copyProperties(image,['system:time_start']);
  return image.addBands(NDWI);

};

//NDWI to the clipped image collection
var withNDWI = clippedCol.map(addNDWI).select('NDWI');

// Test the addNDVI function on a single image.
var ndwi1 = withNDWI.select('NDWI').mean();


var NDWIcolor = {
  min: -1,
  max:1,
  palette: ['0000ff', '00ffff', 'ffff00', 'ff0000', 'ffffff'],
};

// Map.addLayer(ndwi1,NDWIcolor,'test');

// Test the addNDWI function on a single image.
var listOfImages =(withNDWI.toList(withNDWI.size()));
// var firstImage = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(0));
// var secondImage =ee.Image(listOfImages.get(1));
var randomImage=ee.Image(listOfImages.get(7));


Map.centerObject(geometry);
// print('NDWI Images',withNDWI.select('NDWI'));
// Map.addLayer(firstImage,NDWIcolor,'test1');
// Map.addLayer(secondImage,NDWIcolor,'test2');
Map.addLayer(randomImage,NDWIcolor,'Random_Image_test');


//Long-Term Time Series

print(ui.Chart.image.series(withNDWI, geometry, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30));
```

I also get graph which looks nice but now I'm not sure that the data there is correct.

the end goal is to create time series chart graph with the NDWI mean value  for each image.

Comment: Looks like the dark areas are masked out by the cloud mask.

Comment: I tried to check is what you say is true, so I crated list out of the clipped RGB images and retrieved the same number of image , like, image 77 on the original-clippes image collection and image 77 from the NDWI collection, but I got something that has stripes which looks like the sattelite didn't took image but the polygon is small. I dont know how to add image here to demonstrate but I don't think it's clouds

Comment: Could it be related to the scan line issue with LS 7? http://fundisa.sansa.org.za/resources%20-%20Landsat%207%20Products.html